# While loop inside for loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have this code as an example:

```
for i in func(x):
    count = 1
    while i > 0:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            print("(:")
            count += 2
        else:
            print("(:")
            count += 2
```

Or this one:

```
for i in func(x):
    count = 0
    if count % 2 == 0:
        print("(:")
        count += 1
    else:
        print(":(")
        count += 1
```

They don't work as I want them to work.

The first one just enters in an infinite loop, the second one only prints the happy smiley
I want it to print the happy smiley then the sad smiley an so on

This is the original [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vnyn.png)

Comment: You didn't tell us what result you want to get and you telling us 'They don't work as I want them to work.'. So how do you expect us to know what you trying to produce? We don't have psychic mind reader ability.

Comment: @Sky I updated with the result I want

Comment: Does `func(x)` ever return a number <=0?  Also the first loop will always hit the else condition.

Comment: Need to know what's func(x). The problem seems to be in there.

Comment: @Sky  `def gruseis(num):
    bina6 = int(num)
    _bina6 = bina6
    if bina6 != 0:
        while bina6 > 0:
            bina6 %= 1000000
            yield bina6
            bina6 = _bina6 // 1000000
            _bina6 = bina6
    else:
        bina6 = "0"
        yield bina6`        sorry, don't know how to comment with code

Comment: I don't see the variable (x), and what language is this in so I could reference to the function - func.

Comment: What does `func(x)` return? In the first loop, if `i` is larger than 0 to start with, nothing changes it in the loop, so it goes on for ever.  And the printed strings are both `(:`.

Comment: @Sky added the original code as I wrote it on the post, it's on python

Comment: I don't code in python but seeing your code and for loop, seems to be that func(x) itself is only 1 object in this case and it will loop only once due to one object. What you probably looking for is this though, looping from 0 to the return value of the gruseis function - 

for grupbin in range(0, gruseis("10010101")):

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `i` and `count` as two different values to use while iterating, and I don't think you need to do this to get what you want.

First of all - a `while` statement is basically a loop that runs until it is False. So if you have

```
green = True
while green:
    print("Hello")
```

...this will never end. Placing the `while` in a `for` loop doesn't change that; it simply waits for the `while my_condition` to turn False.

Additionally, in your first loop you are incrementing `count` -- but the `while` loop is looking at the value of `i`, which never gets a chance to change because the `while` never becomes untrue!

Finally - in your second loop, you're setting `count` at the beginning of each iteration! This means that `count` will never actually progress in a meaningful way; you set it to 0, print an emoticon, increment it by 2, then continue in the `for` loop - resetting `count` to 0!

Basically, just realize that you can use `i` directly, there's no need for a `count` variable as well. `for i in something` will iterate over whatever is in `something` if it is an iterable thing. So for example:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(":)")
    else:
        print(":(")
```

**EDIT:** After seeing the original code, it looks like you are trying to produce a generator object.

Using `yield` in conjunction with `while` or `for` will net you a generator - an object you can iterate over. Here's a baseline example of that.

```
>>> def baz(x):
...     i = 0
...     while i > x:
...             yield i
...             i += 1
>>> baz(4)
<generator object baz at 0x1004935a0>
>>> me = baz(4)
>>> me.next()
0
>>> me.next()
1
>>> me.next()
2
>>> me.next()
3
>>> me.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

In a situation where you just want to generate a set number of objects, you can skip the `while` and just write a `for`, which will save you a couple of lines. For example, the following code does the same as the above:

```
def foo(x):
    for i in range(0, x):
        yield i
```

However, in the example you've shown me there seems to be some more involved math during the `while` loop, so it does make sense to use a `while` sometimes. Imagine a situation where you wanted to exit the loop when `i` became prime, for example…

```
def until_prime(x):
    while is_not_prime(x): ## or, 'while not is_prime(x)', whatever our imaginary function does
        x = x * (x + 1)
        yield x
```

I have no idea if the code above will ever generate a prime number, so please don't judge it too harshly. :D Nevertheless, it is an example of a situation where you couldn't necessarily write a `for` loop, so you'd need to wait until a condition arose.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the first loop never ends, but if `i` is relevant at a later stage, the `enumerate` answer I put below might be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) function. It appears that `i` is never used, but that is actually irrelevant.

The enumerate function takes an iterable (so anything you can loop over) and returns a tuple with the count and each item in order.

```
for index,item in func(x):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        print("(:")
    else:
        print(":(")
```

This way, even if you don't use `i` (or in the above case `item`) *yet*, you have the option of doing so in the future.